# How to send whatsapp message using whatsapp-web.js to Group member?

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

Below is the sample code that i found to send message to spesific number using whatsapp-web.js. How i do the same thing and send message to Group in Whatsapp?

```
client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('Client is ready!');

  // Number where you want to send the message.
 const number = "+911234567890";

  // Your message.
 const text = "Hey john";

  // Getting chatId from the number.
  // we have to delete "+" from the beginning and add "@c.us" at the end of the number.
 const chatId = number.substring(1) + "@c.us";

 // Sending message.
 client.sendMessage(chatId, text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get all chats (https://docs.wwebjs.dev/Client.html#getChats), filter by group subject or similar and then send to the group `group.sendMessage(message)` or use `client.sendMessage(group.id, message)`